# Assign http response to Observable

Tags: firebase, ionic3, observable, angular-http, angular-observable

What I did was creating a cloud function instead of doing this:

```
if (organizeby === "Most rating") {
    this.restaurantsRef = this.afDb.list('/restaurants', ref => ref.orderByChild('rating'));
    this.restaurantsList = this.restaurantsRef.valueChanges();
}
```

Which was working but I created a cloud function and now what I want to do is this:

```
if (organizeby === "Most rating") {
     this.http.get('https://us-central1-onthespot-bfc6f.cloudfunctions.net/getSortedRestaurantsList')
       .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('data', data.json());
            this.restaurantsList = data.json();
       })
    }
```

The console.log shows me the correct list but the response isn't rendered what am I doint wrong here?

Here is the template:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurantsList | async | termSearch:proptype:'tags'" margin-bottom>
        <div class="card-img-wrap">
            <ion-fab bottom right edge>
                <button ion-fab mini (click)="favorite(restaurant)">
                    <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-fab>
            <img src="{{restaurant.thumbnail}}" tappable (click)="openRestaurantDetail(restaurant)">
            <span ion-text class="card-img-price fw700 text-black">
                {{ restaurant.tags }}
            </span>
            <span ion-text class="card-img-status fw500 text-white" [ngClass]="{'closed': restaurant.label === 'closed', 'open': restaurant.label === 'open'}">
                {{ restaurant.label }}
            </span>
        </div>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title ion-text color="dark" class="fw700" tappable (click)="openRestaurantDetail(restaurant)" no-margin no-padding>
                {{restaurant.title}}
            </ion-card-title>
            <p ion-text color="primary" no-margin>
                {{restaurant.city}}, {{restaurant.state}} •
                <span ion-text class="fw700">{{ restaurant.price }}</span>
            </p>
            <hr>
            <ion-badge color="secondary">
                <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
                {{ restaurant.rating | number:'1.1' }}
            </ion-badge>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Comment: show us the template where you are using this.restaurantsList.

Comment: @Luillyfe here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `async pipe`

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurantsList | async | termSearch:proptype:'tags'" margin-bottom>
```

You no longer need to make an explicit subscription to:

```
this.http.get('https://us-central1-onthespot-bfc6f.cloudfunctions.net/getSortedRestaurantsList')
```

Just leave that `Angular async pipe` control the subscription (import the `map operator`).

```
if (organizeby === "Most rating") {
  this.restaurantsList = this.http.get('https://us-central1-onthespot-bfc6f.cloudfunctions.net/getSortedRestaurantsList')
    .map(data => data.json());
}
```

Let me know how that works !

Comment: It works when I assign this to restaurantList = return this.httpClient.get(this.sortedRestaurantsURL)
                .map(response => response)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the subscribe method scope of `this` has changed so if you need to call parents `this` you will have to define it with different name.
 try this.

```
  let self=this;
    if (organizeby === "Most rating") {
         this.http.get('https://us-central1-onthespot-bfc6f.cloudfunctions.net/getSortedRestaurantsList')
           .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log('data', data.json());
                self.restaurantsList = data.json();
           })
        }
```